# Regex to identify all Comment blocks in a Code

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex

Am working towards a Code in Salesforce APEX to identify all Comment blocks in a Code.

In a Bigger Prospect, I want to inspect lines of Code to check if there is any Best Practises error.

For this, I need Line Calculation to be correct and hence want to concert Comment blocks into single lines.

However, all the patterns I have tried are going into infinite loops.

I am looking for regex Patter which would return 3 matches for below type of code:-

```
/* hey

*ru

*there

*/

Some COde

/* hey

*ru

*there

*/

Some Code
/* hey

*ru

*there

*/

Some Code
```

The options which I have already tried are as below:-

```
\\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\\*+
(/\\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\\*+/) 
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

But none of this works.

Can someone help me with better string?

Comment: Try `/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/`. I am not sure you can use non-capturing groups, if yes, `/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/` should also work.

Comment: What is the code you used?

Comment: Have a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file%3F

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the comment blocks you can use following regex on the complete code (not by line):

```
/(/\*.*?\*/)/sg
```

You have to use the singleline and global modifier to have all comments returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Apex docs, it looks like you are looking for a Java-compatible regex.

You may rely on

```
"/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m3uno3/1)

**Details**:

- `/\*` - literal `/*` susbtring
- `[^*]*\*+` - match 0+ chars other than `*` and then one or more literal asterisks
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - any char other than `/` or `*` (see`[^/*]`) followed with zero or more  characters other than asterisk (`[^*]*`) followed with one or more asterisks (`\*+`)
- `/` - closing `/` symbol.